# AVAssetWriter Unable to record audio with video | Crashing

Tags: ios, swift, camera, avfoundation, avassetwriter

I am trying to capture video/Audio frames from `CMSampleBuffer` but completely failing to obtain a proper video recording.

**Expected Output:**
A Video file in `.mp4` format that has both audio(from the mic) and video frames.

**Current Output:**
An Empty Directory/A video file without audio.

**Crashes on Run** : `Media type of sample buffer must match receiver's media type ("soun")`

I tried almost everything available online to troubleshoot this. I have a deadline coming and I just pulling my hair trying to figure out what exactly is going on. Any help/pointers are highly appreciated.

Below is the source.

`CameraController.swift`

```
class CameraController: UIViewController, SFrameCaptureDelegate {
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        setupUI()
        
        assetWriter = AssetManager(filename: UUID().uuidString.appending(".mp4"))
        frameBuffer.delegate = self
        frameBuffer.startSession()
        
    }
    
    
    var previewView: PreviewView = {
        let instance = PreviewView()
        return instance
    }()
    
    var frameBuffer = FrameCapture(type: .AudioVideo)
    
    var captureButton: UIButton = {
        let instance = UIButton()
        instance.setTitle("Capture", for: .normal)
        instance.backgroundColor = .white
        return instance
    }()
 
    // if the user is recording the frames from the phone
    var frameCaptureRunning = false
    
    var assetWriter : AssetManager!
    
    var videoDirectoryPath = SFileManager.shared.getDocumentDirectory()
    
    func setupUI() {
        
        view.addSubview(previewView)
        previewView.top(to: view)
        previewView.left(to: view)
        previewView.right(to: view)
        previewView.height(view.frame.height)
        
        previewView.session = frameBuffer.session
        
        
        view.addSubview(captureButton)
        captureButton.size(CGSize(width: 100, height: 100))
        captureButton.centerX(to: view)
        captureButton.bottom(to: view, offset: -20)
        captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(startpic), for: .touchDown)
        captureButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopic), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func startpic() {
        frameCaptureRunning = true
        assetWriter.isRecording = true
    }
    
    @objc func stopic() {
        frameCaptureRunning = false
        assetWriter.isRecording = false
        assetWriter.finish {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let activity = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [self.assetWriter.url!], applicationActivities: nil)
                self.present(activity, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }
            print("This -- ",self.assetWriter.url.path)
            do {
                let attr = try FileManager.default.attributesOfItem(atPath: self.assetWriter.url.path)
                let fileSize = attr[FileAttributeKey.size] as! UInt64
                print("H264 file size = \(fileSize)")

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    let player = AVPlayer(url: self.assetWriter.url)
                    let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
                    playerLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                    playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
                    playerLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                    self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
                    player.play()
                }
            }catch{
                print("issues with finishing")
            }
        }
        
        
    }
    
    func capturedFrame(buffers: CMSampleBuffer) {
        
        if !frameCaptureRunning { return }
        assetWriter.write(buffer: buffers)
        
    }
    
}
```

`FrameCapture.swift`

```
protocol SFrameCaptureDelegate: class {
    func capturedFrame(buffers: CMSampleBuffer)
}

class FrameCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate, AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    
    init(type: SessionType) {
        super.init()
        print("SFC - Frame Buffers initialized with Config - ", type.self)
        sessionType = type
    }
    
    func startSession() {
        print("SFC - Frame Buffers Session Starting")
        sessionQueue.async {
            self.configureSession(type: self.sessionType)
            self.session.startRunning()
        }
    }
    
    weak var delegate: SFrameCaptureDelegate?
    
    enum SessionSetupResult {
        case success
        case notAuthorized
        case configurationFailed
    }
    
    enum SessionType {
        case Audio
        case Video
        case AudioVideo
    }
    
    let session = AVCaptureSession()
    let sessionQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "sessionQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
    let videoQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "videoQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
    let audioQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audioQueue", qos: .userInitiated)
    var setupResult: SessionSetupResult = .success
    var sessionType: SessionType = .Video
    
    @objc dynamic var videoDeviceInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput!
    let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
    let audioOutput = AVCaptureAudioDataOutput()
    var photoQualityPrioritizationMode: AVCapturePhotoOutput.QualityPrioritization = .balanced
    
///  MARK: SessionConfig
    func configureSession(type: SessionType) {
        
        if setupResult != .success { return }
        
        session.beginConfiguration()
        session.sessionPreset = .high
        
        do {
            var defaultVideoDevice: AVCaptureDevice?
            
            if let dualCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInDualWideCamera, for: .video, position: .back) {
                defaultVideoDevice = dualCameraDevice
            } else if let backCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .back){
                defaultVideoDevice = backCameraDevice
            } else if let frontCameraDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(.builtInWideAngleCamera, for: .video, position: .front){
                defaultVideoDevice = frontCameraDevice
            }
            
            guard let videoDevice = defaultVideoDevice else {
                print("CAM - Camera unavailable")
                setupResult = .configurationFailed
                session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }
            
            let videoInputDevice = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoDevice)
            
            if session.canAddInput(videoInputDevice) {
                session.addInput(videoInputDevice)
                videoDeviceInput = videoInputDevice
            } else {
                print("CAM - Couldn't add input to the session")
                setupResult = .configurationFailed
                session.commitConfiguration()
                return
            }
        } catch {
            print("CAM - Couldn't create device input. Error - ", error.localizedDescription)
            setupResult = .configurationFailed
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }
        
        if sessionType == .AudioVideo {
            do {
                let audioDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .audio)
                let audioDeviceInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: audioDevice!)
                print("SFC - in audio device input")
                if session.canAddInput(audioDeviceInput) {
                    session.addInput(audioDeviceInput)
                } else { print("CAM - Couldn't add audio input device to session.") }
            } catch { print("couldn't create audio input device. Error - ",error.localizedDescription) }
        }
        
        
        videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: videoQueue)
        if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
            session.addOutput(videoOutput)
            photoQualityPrioritizationMode = .balanced
        } else {
            print("Could not add photo output to the session")
            setupResult = .configurationFailed
            session.commitConfiguration()
            return
        }
        
        if sessionType == .AudioVideo {
            audioOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: audioQueue)
            if session.canAddOutput(audioOutput) {
                session.addOutput(audioOutput)
            } else {
                print("Couldn't add audio output")
                setupResult = .configurationFailed
                session.commitConfiguration()
            }
        }
        
        videoOutput.connections.first?.videoOrientation = .portrait
        videoOutput.videoSettings = [ kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA ]
        videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
        
        session.commitConfiguration()

    }
    
/// MARK: CMSampleBufferDelegate
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        self.delegate?.capturedFrame(buffers: sampleBuffer)
    }
    
}
```

`AssetManager.swift`

```
class AssetManager: NSObject {
    
    private var assetWriter: AVAssetWriter?
    private var videoInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    private var audioInput: AVAssetWriterInput?
    var url: URL!
    
    let writerQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "writerQueue", qos: .utility)
    
    var isRecording = false
    var video_frames_written = false
    
    init(filename: String) {
        super.init()
        self.videoDirectory.appendPathComponent(filename)
        self.url = self.videoDirectory
        
    }

    private var videoDirectory = SFileManager.shared.getDocumentDirectory()

    
    private func setupWriter() {
        
        SFileManager.shared.clearPreviousFiles(withPath: videoDirectory.path)
        SFileManager.shared.createNewDirectory(withPath: videoDirectory.path)
        printLog(item: self.videoDirectory)
        
        
        self.assetWriter = try? AVAssetWriter(outputURL: self.videoDirectory, fileType: AVFileType.mp4)
        
        let videoOutputSettings = [
            AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
            AVVideoHeightKey: 1280,
            AVVideoWidthKey:720
        ] as [String : Any]
        
        
        self.videoInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .video, outputSettings: videoOutputSettings)
        self.videoInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        if let videoInput = self.videoInput, (self.assetWriter?.canAdd(videoInput))! {
            self.assetWriter?.add(videoInput)
        }
        
        
        let audioOutputSettings = [
            AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
            AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1,
            AVSampleRateKey: 44100,
            AVEncoderBitRateKey: 64000
        ] as [String: Any]
        
        
        self.audioInput = AVAssetWriterInput(mediaType: .audio, outputSettings: audioOutputSettings)
        self.audioInput?.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = true
        if let audioInput = self.audioInput, (self.assetWriter?.canAdd(audioInput))! {
            self.assetWriter?.add(audioInput)
            printDone(item: "Asset writer added, \(String(describing: self.audioInput))")
        } else {
            printError(item: "No audio Input")
        }
        
        
    }
    
    
    public func write(buffer: CMSampleBuffer) {
        writerQueue.sync {
            
            if assetWriter == nil { self.setupWriter() }

            if self.assetWriter?.status == .unknown {
                self.assetWriter?.startWriting()
                self.assetWriter?.startSession(atSourceTime: CMSampleBufferGetPresentationTimeStamp(buffer))
                printDone(item: "Started AssetWriter")
            }

            if self.assetWriter?.status == .failed {
                printError(item: "Asset Writer Failed with Error: \(String(describing: self.assetWriter?.error))")
            }

            if CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(buffer) {

                if let videoInput = self.videoInput, videoInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    videoInput.append(buffer)
                }
                
                if let audioInput = self.audioInput, audioInput.isReadyForMoreMediaData {
                    audioInput.append(buffer) // Crashes at this line
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    public func finish(completion: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        writerQueue.async {
            self.assetWriter?.finishWriting(completionHandler: { [self] in
                printDone(item: "Finished Writing")
                completion()
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a video buffer to your `audioInput` and depending on how the buffers arrive, you might also write an audio buffer to your `videoInput`.

In your case, the `CMSampleBuffer`s contain either audio or video, so you append audio buffers to `audioInput` and video buffers to `videoInput`.

You can distinguish the two types of buffer by comparing the `output` in `captureOutput:didOutput:` to your `audioInput` and `videoOutput` or by looking at the buffer's `CMSampleBufferGetFormatDescription()`'s `CMFormatDescriptionGetMediaType()`, but that's more complicated.

Comment: I think I got a little bit of an idea with that. I am on trying it right now. Although, is this the  efficient way, or can it be better?

Comment: I would compare the output

Comment: Mr. Fistman. You help me solve a massive thing. Thanks A BUNCH. Cheers

Comment: Hey Man, I am lately having issues with the first couple of frames being blank. I tried to fix it by waiting until I get the first video frame. But that doesnt seem to help much. Can you please help me find a solution to it.

Comment: Hey @AakashDave do you think you can start a new "why are my first frames blank question" with the capture session and writer code?

Comment: can you help me here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66182937/cidetector-crashing-while-processing-cmsamplebuffer