# CIDetector crashing while processing CMSampleBuffer

Tags: ios, swift, image-processing, avfoundation, vision

Problem:
I am trying to get facial features through CIDetector from CMSampleBuffer from AVCaptureVideoDataOutput. On execution of the program, 9 out of 10 time the program crashes and only once it runs fine.

Expected Output:
Run without crash and print "Happy" on feature detection.

Code:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    
    let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)!
    let opaqueBuffer = Unmanaged<CVImageBuffer>.passUnretained(imageBuffer).toOpaque()
    let pixelBuffer = Unmanaged<CVPixelBuffer>.fromOpaque(opaqueBuffer).takeUnretainedValue()
    let sourceImage = CIImage(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, options: nil)
    let options = [CIDetectorSmile : true as AnyObject, CIDetectorEyeBlink: true as AnyObject, CIDetectorImageOrientation : 6 as AnyObject]
    
    // The detector is nil
    let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options) 
    let features = detector!.features(in: sourceImage, options: options)

        for feature in features as! [CIFaceFeature] {

            if (feature.hasSmile) {
                printLog(item: "HAPPY")
            }
        }
}
```

Crashlog :
`Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.`
The `detector` is nil

Would love help and further pointers.

Comment: Do you use front faceID camera?

Comment: @Aznix yes. I am using front camera. But it's not just faceID, it runs on all devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The return is optional and `sampleBuffer` is called way too heavy you can only do this

```
if let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: options) {
    let features = detector.features(in: sourceImage, options: options) 
    for feature in features as! [CIFaceFeature] { 
        if (feature.hasSmile) {
            printLog(item: "HAPPY")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. Is this the most optimal way or can it be optimized

Comment: as you said some time it returns something correctly that's mean it works but as Apple made it optional this implies that it could fail for some reason with these 2 things together the above is the only available way IMO